# Writing constraint

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, self-study, dynamic-optimization

A firm accumulates useful knowledge $k$ by investing in R&D activities. Specifically, if the firm invests $r > 0$ dollars into R&D, the stock of useful knowledge grows by about $2\sqrt{r}$ units, minus the forgotten knowledge $\delta k$ where $\delta \in (0, 1)$.
Suppose that the firm operates with the so-called Ak production function, with A > 0 being the fixed productivity, and let the price of output be normalized to 1.

The objective function is $$\int_0^{\infty}(Ak-r)e^{-it}dt$$

$k_0>0$ and $i>0$

I just want you to help me writing CONSTRAINT (LAW OF MOTION).

I don’t want you to solve this question. Just help me how to write its constraint according to above info in order to solve for maximization problem with hamiltonian function.

Comment: This seems really straightforward. Could you explain where exactly your difficulty is?

Comment: Indeed, I write $$ \dot{k}=Ak-2\sqrt{r}-\delta k$$ but I am not sure. Is it true? And my another small question is which is control variable and which is state variable here?@Giskard

Comment: "the firm operates with the ... Ak production function": is it producing knowledge, or some other output?

Comment: @AdamBailey I guess only knowledge. All question is this. I don’t know more or less. What is your opinion for constraint?

Comment: @Giskard I would like to learn your opinion please 

Comment: It is impossible to give a definite answer if "All question is this". My guess is $$\dot{k} = Ak+2\sqrt{r}−\delta k$$ (You had a sign error.) My other guess would be $$\dot{k} = 2\sqrt{r}−\delta k,$$ this is if the output of the production function is measured in dollars, not knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ☺️ @Giskard

Comment: I have considered something. The question says useful knowledge grows $2\sqrt{r}$ units, so in the first equation, should we write $=Ak+ 2\sqrt{r}k-\delta k$. I would like to ask you. Thanks. Dear @Giskard

Comment: This is not the place for back and forth...please ask your professor or teacher's assistant if you find the question unclear.

Comment: @user315 It's hard to be sure, but I suspect the production function is about production of some output other than knowledge, and knowledge is just an input into that production function.  If so, then Ak should not appear within the equation for $\dot{k}$.

Comment: I understand. Then, please can you write all possible constraints which you suppose ?@AdamBailey btw, thank you so much for your answer